Last Activity field on Account detail page
When I run a report on accounts I can pull in a field called "Last Activity Date". I'm trying to add this to the account detail page, but it doesn't seem to exist anywhere but the report. I checked the profile permission settings and it's not there. I see documentation on how the field is populated, but can't find anything about it not being available for a detail page. Is there any way to get this?

This is covered in SFDC Help: Show 'Last Activity' on object detail page layout
Basically, you just create a formula field. LastActivityDate is available in Reports and API, not the UX

Create a Custom Field on the object in which you would like to show the 'Last Activity on a record.'
Example: Lead

Classic: Click Setup | Customize | Leads | Fields
Lightning Experience: Click the gear icon then Setup | Object Manager | Lead | Fields & Relationships

Click New

Select the Data Type as Formula and click Next

Choose output Type as Date and Enter the Field label of your choice.Then Next

Enter the formula as given below:


a) Click on Advanced Formula
b) Click on Insert Field
c) Choose Last Activity field (API Name: LastActivityDate) then click the Insert button.
d) Check Syntax then Next.
e) Select the visibility of this field for various profiles.
f) Add it to the Page Layout where the field should be visible and click Save.
Result: You can track the last activity date on the record detail page layout.

